# Feasibility Of Entity Centric Indexing for my use case

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch

We're collecting all the events in our application and storing them along with a session identifier. I've an use case where i want to find the sessions where users navigate from say login page to product page to cart page . We're consolidating all the events happening to an entity centric index (based on session identifier) and all events are stored as a nested field.

sample document
`{"session_id": 1, "paths": [{"event": "pageload", "view": "A", "timestamp": 1589584620000}, {"event": "pageload", "view": "C", "timestamp": 1589584680000}, {"event": "pageload", "view": "B", "timestamp": 1589584700000}]}`
I tried the below query

```
POST entity_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "step1": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "paths",
          "query": {
            "match": {"paths.view": "A"}
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "step2": {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "paths",
              "query": {
                "match": {"paths.view": "D"}
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "step3": {
              "filter": {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "paths",
                  "query": {
                    "match": {"paths.view": "B"}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the order of navigations is not maintained . Is it possible to achieve my use case without using script aggregation ? Is Elastic search suitable for this use case or should we try other graph databases?